# Read input char without pressing RET

Tags: interactive, read

I want to perform the same task as in the function below, but without having to press ENTER every time I select an option.

```
(defun my-fun ()
  (interactive)
  (setq something (read-string "Options:\n [m]: Do A.\n [n] Do B.\nINPUT: "))
  (pcase something
    ("m" (insert "m pressed\n"))
    ("n" (insert "n pressed\n")))
  (my-fun))
```

What is the correct way to do it? It is probably a basic function (some alternative to read string?), but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: you may be interested in hydra as a mode to do just that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently want to read a character and immediately dispatch behavior based on what it is.

**Help** > **Search Documentation** > **Find Any Object by Name** (command `apropos`) tells you, for `read` plus `char` tells you about function **`read-char`**.

`C-h f read-char`:

> **`read-char`** is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> `(read-char &optional PROMPT INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD SECONDS)`
>
> Read a character from the command input (keyboard or macro).
>   It is returned as a number.
>   If the character has modifiers, they are resolved and reflected to the
>       character code if possible (e.g. `C-SPC` -> 0).
>
> If the user generates an event which is not a character (i.e. a mouse
>       click or function key event), `read-char` signals an error.  As an
>       exception, switch-frame events are put off until non-character events
>       can be read.
>
> If you want to read non-character events, or ignore them, call
>       `read-event` or `read-char-exclusive` instead.
>
> If the optional argument `PROMPT` is non-nil, display that as a prompt.
>
> If the optional argument `INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD` is non-nil and some
>       input method is turned on in the current buffer, that input method
>       is used for reading a character.
>
> If the optional argument `SECONDS` is non-nil, it should be a number
>       specifying the maximum number of seconds to wait for input.  If no
>       input arrives in that time, return nil.  `SECONDS` may be a
>       floating-point value.

Comment: That's it! I only had to change "m" to 109 and so on...

Comment: @Jacek if you want something more readable, you can use `?m` as the character literal that evaluates to `109`.